# get the ip address from mulitple mapped network drives vbscript and then use it

Tags: vbscript

i'm trying to create a script to remove mapped network drives of roaming users
that is if there mapping is not the same as their current subnet 
for example : if the user sits on subnet 10.10.50 , and has mapped network drive of 
10.10.40 , the mapping will be removed (but it has to be general script cause my company has almost 50 branches/subnets .
my problem is getting the ip address from the enumrating mapped drives (it's enumarting into an array using 
and then split it via split operation in vbscript

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, colDrives, i, DriveLetter, DrivePath

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
' extra section to troubleshoot
If colDrives.Count= 0 Then
WScript.Echo "Guy's Warning: No Drive Mapped "
WScript.Quit(0)
End If

' here is where the script reads the Array

Dim DriveServer
For i = 0 To colDrives.Count -1 Step 2 ' this check the drive letter list 
DriveLetter = colDrives.item(i)  ' this follows drive letter
DrivePath = colDrives.Item(i+1)
If Len(DriveLetter) > 0 Then
DriveServer = getServerFromPath(DrivePath)
If Not Ping(DriveServer) Then
objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive DriveLetter, True, True
End If
End If
Next
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how did the results differ from what you expected?

Comment: hi there , i have enumarted the network mapped drivers , following that i got the list of drivers enumrated including drive letter for example z: - \\1234\fjfkj\ second line , x: -\\5532\fjjeh etc.. , there is 3 mapped drivers, the problem is extracting the server name for the mapped drive full path (a.k.a the first name which give us the ip address of the server to compare with current local computer ip address . ( i don't have an idea how to do it...(extract the ip from the shared mapped network address .

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the servername or IP address from a path `\\10.10.50.23\share` like this:

```
Function GetServerFromPath(p)
  GetServerFromPath = Split(Mid(p, 3), "\")(0)
End Function

WScript.Echo GetServerFromPath("\\10.10.50.23\share")
```

Comment: dear, first of all thank u for answer , but the script doesn't work for me(maybe i'm doing something wrong ...:<) , anyway i will try to explain better , our company has over 1000 stations with approx 50 subnets , i need a script to remove "unwanted shared network drivers" from stations that sit on adifferenet subnet then the one mapped in their mapped share network drives only . , so the network quality bandwidth will be kept . can u help me aheiving this script ? it has to be a general script .

Comment: @user3088460 "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. How *exactly* is the result you got different from the result you expected? Besides, in this kind of network you should have the subnets associated with AD sites and map the drives via site-specific policies.